# laravel 4 installation with wamp only show directories of laravel

Tags: php, git, laravel

I am a newbie to `laravel` framework . I tried to install it into `wamp` ( windows 7) following some tutorials. I tried to follow their official website, but is it ambiguous to me.
After I completed the installation, I opened `localhost/laravel` which displayed the directory of laravel .Here are the steps that I follow:

1- Download laravle-master.zip
2- Uncommented all `openssl` commands from php and apache configuration files.
3- install `composer` ( it gave me a note that the environment path will be changed).
4- Run the command `composer install`  in `git bash` cli

Please give me any information that may help me. The problem with most of the tutorials that they are skipping many important steps for the beginners.

Comment: The site will be accessible through `localhost/laravel/public`. You can serve the current site with Artisan, that doesn't depend on Apache, you can put your project on any folder and run `php artisan serve`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working now. but the website is still displayed as a directory. Why?

Answer (score 7):

Laravel has a folder `public`, that's where the index of your site is, so to access it you'd go to `localhost/laravel/public`.

But Laravel also provides a quick testing server that's built into PHP. To quickly start a new project with Composer already installed you'd do:

```
# Create folder anywhere you'd like
mkdir laravel && cd laravel
# Get latest Laravel with dependencies
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
# Run website with PHP's built-in server
./artisan serve
```

Now if you go to `localhost:8000` you''ll get the Laravel intro page and you're ready to start developing.

If you decide use Apache and you want to get rid of `/public` you'd have to create a virtual host so you can link a domain to the public folder. More info http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html